# Google Map new map renderer problem (play-services-maps:18.0.0)

Tags: android, google-maps-android-api-2

I updated to 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:18.0.0' and now custom marker images are behaving strange.

At the images below, blue thing and the label is two separate markers with custom icons.

If there is not much marker(or Renderer.LEGACY) everything works as normal. Like this:

[image]

But if there is too many marker and Renderer.LATEST then markers became like this:

[image]

I updated from 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:17.0.0' to 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:18.0.0'

EDIT: I updatet to 18.0.2 and now markers at bottom are gone completely

[image]

Comment: As I understand, currently, even if app is updated to use `18.0.0` of Google Maps, still an old renderer is used by default. We can force to use new renderer to make sure that it's working fine. Hopefully some one from Maps team will spot your question and give some feedback.